# Decorate Angular's $log to use a service that uses $http

Tags: angularjs, http, logging, decorator

I am trying to extend the `$log` service so that it also sends a message to a server. I am getting an error from Angular "*Circular dependency found*" as `$http` uses `$log`.

app.js:

```
angular.module("app").config(function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator("$log", function($delegate, NodeLogger) {
        var logFn = $delegate.log;
        $delegate.log = function(message) {
            NodeLogger.log(message);
            logFn.apply(null, arguments);
        };
    });
});
```

NodeLogger.js:

```
angular.module("app").factory("NodeLogger", function($http) {

    function log(type, message) {
        var logMessage = type + ":" + message;
        $http.post("http://localhost:3000/log", "message=" + logMessage);
    }

    return {
        log: log
    }
});
```

I have tried using `$injector` in `app.js` to load `$http` and just make the `POST` request, but it gives the same error. Is there a way to get around this? Can I avoid using `$http` / `$resource`?

Thanks!

Comment: don't use service or factory directly , instead use injector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common issue of circular dependency when `$http` already injects `$log` and by decorating it with injecting your factory `NodeLogger` which inturn injects `$http` you are creating circular dependency. Instead of injecting your factory directly get the factory from injector, another way is to inject the `$injector` in your factory and get the `$http` instance from injector instead of injecting `$http` directly. This way you avoid circular dependency during factory creation. One important note is to return `$delegate` without which `$log` service will not hold any instance.

```
$provide.decorator("$log", function($delegate, $injector) {
    var logFn = $delegate.log;
    $delegate.log = function(message) {

      //Get NodeLogger factory instance from injector
      var NodeLogger = $injector.get('NodeLogger');
      NodeLogger.log(message);
      logFn.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    //Return the delegate
    return $delegate;
  });
```

```js
angular.module("app", []).factory("NodeLogger", function($http) {

  function log(type, message) {
    var logMessage = type + ":" + message;
    $http.post("http://localhost:3000/log", "message=" + logMessage);
  }

  return {
    log: log
  }
}).config(function($provide) {
  $provide.decorator("$log", function($delegate, $injector) {
    var logFn = $delegate.log;
    $delegate.log = function(message) {
      var NodeLogger = $injector.get('NodeLogger');
      NodeLogger.log(message);
      logFn.apply(null, arguments);
    };
    return $delegate;
  });
}).run(function($log) {
  $log.log("Hey");
});;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it for me :)

Comment: If that doesn't work, make sure you didn't put the $injector.get() code outside of the anonymous function set to $delegate.log, like I did ! In that case, you still have the circular dependency.